# Grouping Sets SQL - records will all NULL values in the result

Tags: sql, presto, grouping-sets

If I create 4 grouping sets in my query, e.g.

```
GROUP BY
GROUPING SETS ((a), (b), (c), (d))
```

Why does it create 4 records with all NULL values ?

I understand if I use a blank grouping set  like () this calculated the totals if I am right and in this case all individual values for dimensions should be NULL but the metric values should be calculated.

But in my case, I need values grouped by individual dimensions only and it does calculate correctly and I am able to fetch using  select * from xyz where a is not NULL for data grouped by a

But I am not able to understand why does it create records will all NULL values. The number of records looks like is the same as number of grouping sets. So does it create one row per grouping set?

Can someone please explain the logic?

I was expecting to see grouped by one of each the dimensions I used in my grouping sets. I was not expecting to see a record with all NULL values created per grouping set

Comment: Can you show examples of your source data and the full query you are running?

Comment: agg AS (
    SELECT
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        AVG(a)  AS avg_a,
        AVG(b)  AS avg_b,
 AVG(b)  AS avg_c,
  AVG(b)  AS avg_d,
  AVG(b)  AS avg_e,
    FROM fact
    GROUP BY
        grouping sets (
            (a),
            (b),
            (c),
            (d),
            (e)
        )
)

select * from agg where a is NULL and b is NULL and c is NULL and d is NULL and e is NULL

It returns 5 records with a,b,c,d,e  with NULL values but metrics calculated. Does this mean that its calculating the overall value per grouping set ?

Comment: Do NOT use these comments for code - instead EDIT your question - there is a link under the tags for that. Also note you should include the FULL query and and example of the output that highlights the rows you do not want. Ideally you would provide `sample data` and `expected result`

Comment: `GROUPING SETS` is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. You are asking it for four separate resultsets concatenated together: each grouped by a or b or c or d or e respectively. Any column used bare in the query without an aggregation function will show as `NULL` in the other rows. So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no null values in all of the columns?